# Properties of inverse Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

Is it possible for $A^3$ to be an Identity matrix without A being invertibe?

If I do the following would it be correct:

$A$.$A^2$= I

Therefore A has to be invertible

Comment: You're correct.  You can also look at determinants.  $\det (A^3) = (\det A)^3.$

Answer (score 3):

You are fully correct: from $A^3=I$ you get
$$
AA^2=I=A^2A
$$
so $A^2$ qualifies as the inverse of $A$.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/787264)

Comment: @amWhy Really? What do you think an answer should be?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if $A^3=I$ then $\det A^3 =\det I$

We know that $\det I=1$ hence $\det A^3=1$ which means $\det A \neq 0$ . Therefore $A$ is invertible.